# Issue with cron jobs

Tags: database, cron

I’m currently working with cronjob assets. I have certain cronjobs in a database, that I need to execute in the crontab. I need this to be automatic. Lets say that I have a page where I'm filling my databases with certain cronjobs, when I finish saving the crons in the database, there is a button that say , "load this cronjobs". So , when I press the button, all the cronjobs that are in the database are upload to the crontab. How can I do that? Is it possible?

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: It is very possible, but you probably need to write some custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the crontab format isn't that hard to create and the files are plain ascii, so you won't need any exotic api's to manipulate them.

The main issue will probably be interference with manual editing.  This can be solved by integrating a comment block in the crontab file that makes clear that a real user should not mess with the jobs below the comment.  Everytime your app reads the crontab file it can safely delete and recreate everything below the comment block.

```
56 9 * * * /some/path/to/some/manually/executed/script
#
# ALL JOBS AFTER THIS LINE IS MANAGED BY MYSUPERAPP.  NO MANUAL MODIFICATIONS !
# 
56 9 * * * /some/path/to/thefirst/database-extracted/script
```

ps: resist the temptation of messing with crontab files directly, always use the crontab utility to avoid confusing the cron daemon.